# Using xpath for looking at specific elements to scrape

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get some information from a website, scamadviser.com.
In particular I'd interested in the final score in the shield (for example, for stackoverflow.com check the value in the shield is 100%).
I've tried to inspect it, and I see that the path is: [image]

I did

```
def scam(df):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    trust=[]
    country = [] 
    isp_country = [] 
        
    urls=['stackoverflow.com','GitHub.com']
    driver=webdriver.Chrome('mypath',chrome_options=chrome_options))
    
    for x in urls:
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        response=driver.get('https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/'+x)
        
        try: 
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
            
            t=driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'trust__overlay shield-color--green') and contains(text(),'icon')]")).get_attribute('innerText')
            trust.append(t)  

            c=driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block__col') and contains(text(),'Country')]")).get_attribute('innerText')
            country.append(c)  

           ic=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block__col') and contains(text(),'ISP')]").get_attribute('innerText')
            isp_country.append(ic)
        
        except: 
            trust.append("Error")
            country.append("Error")
            isp_country.append("Error")
            

    # Create dataframe
    dict = {'URL': urls, 'Trust':trust, 'Country': country, 'ISP': isp_country} 
    df=pd.DataFrame(dict)

    driver.quit()
    
    return df
```

but the dataframe created contains only `Errors` (i.e., it executes only the `except` in the `try/except`).

I can't understand if the error is due to the try/except and/or to the way I look at the element (using xpath). Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Can you directly share the URL ? I see few issues with your code. I tried this `https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/stackoverflow.com`, also when you are scrolling, have a separate statement for scrolling and then try to interact with the web element/elements using Explicit waits. I can provide you an optimal solution but I need to see the page by myself.

Comment: I can confirm the url: https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/stackoverflow.com (and https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/github.com)

Comment: okay I am here `https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/stackoverflow.com` You wanna get the company info such as `Organisation
Stack Exchange, Inc.
Owner
Sysadmin Team
Address
110 William St , Floor 28 10038 New York NY
Country
US
Phone
Non-Public Data
E-mail
https://www.name.com/contact-domain-whois/stackoverflow.com/registrant` ? This is my question.

Comment: Also using selenium windows I see this `Checking your browser before accessing scamadviser.com.
This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.

Please allow up to 5 seconds…

DDoS protection by Cloudflare`

Comment: I cannot see any other URL except that one I mention. All the information seems to be included on the same webpage, just scrolling down. I am try to get information about Trustscore (the shield) and countries (unfortunately I am still struggling in getting this info). I do not know how I can get your same url or message (checking your browser before accessing...)for extracting this info (so, yes, I would also extract some information on registrant, server...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the OP response and for this particular ticket, to get the `trusted score` from the website mentioned by OP, the below `xpath` has `1/1 matching node in HTML DOM.`

**Xpath :-**

```
//div[text()='Trustscore']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::div[@class='icon']
```

You do not need to scroll for this web element, cause as soon as windows is launched, trusted score is in Selenium view port.

Use it with `explicit waits` like this :

```
trusted_score = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Trustscore']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::div[@class='icon']")))
print(trusted_score.text)
```

for this you'll need imports as well.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**PS :** Make sure Selenium windows is launched in full screen mode.

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

**Update 1 :**

```
data = {'URL': urls, 
        'Trust': trust, 
        'Country': country, 
        'ISP': isp_country}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: Don't insert into dataframes yet. Just print that, `print(trusted_score.text)` and see if we have got something on console. Also, comment df lines. Also just not the path, use the entire code, we have to debug this step by steps to see where it is exactly going wrong.

Comment: remove everything and pass just the `'Trust': trust`

Comment: it would work only if I replace there `trusted_score.text`. I guess it would be the same also for the other country variables.

Comment: I believe in df you are passing the list, right ? yes you will have to append into the list first with `.text`, cause that's how we printed on the console.